# How does an interface work internally?

Tags: c#

In C#, an interface is a bit different from C++ with pure virtual functions or Java.

In C# methods in an interface don't act like virtual functions, unlike other major compile-languages, which means we *can not override* them.

```
interface IMyInterface 
{
    void Foo();
}

class Root : IMyInterface 
{
    public void Foo() { ... } // OK.
}

class Child : Root
{
    public void Foo() { ... } // Not overrided.
]
```

So I assume that in that case the interface doesn't even contain vtable either.

Without that or anything that points to the function address, how  do the interfaces in C# know where the designated methods to invoke are, internally?

Comment: They are bound dynamically at runtime.  You get a big fat warning from the compiler for this code, it is pretty convinced that you got it wrong.  You probably did.  Sure you can override them, just declare the implementation method as *virtual*.

Comment: @HansPassant "They are bound dynamically at runtime", this is generally speaking an incorrect statement. c# is not a dynamic language, at least not in this respect. the binding is done in a very well defined manner known at compilation time.

Comment: No, the CLR does this at runtime.  The compiler merely expresses the contract in the IL.

Comment: @HansPassant 1. in most cases you are sort of right, because the actual "binding" happens during JIT compilation. 2. Except that you can compile C# to machine code in several ways, and then it will all happen at compile time. 3. Usually when people say "Dynamic" in the context of programming they refer to the way "Dynamic Programming Languages" behave. In this sense if you look at it from the C# semantics point of view, there's nothing dynamic about it. in the sense of language semantics it's exactly as dynamic as C++ virtual methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're confusing interfaces with inheritance..

in your example above `Root` implements IMyInterface and exposes the traits defined in `IMyInterface`. on a completely different note `Child` inharits all of `Root`'s implementation and most expose a super-set of the same traits.

in fact you could override `Foo` in `Child`, and also reimplement if you use explisit interface implementation (name it `IMyInterface.Foo`)

so you can:

```
    interface IMyInterface 
{
    void Foo();
}
class Root : IMyInterface 
{
    public virtual void Foo() {  } 
}

class Child : Root
{
    public override void Foo() { } 

       void IMyInterface.Foo() { } 

}
```

---

regarding :

> Without that or anything that points to the function address, how do
>   the interfaces in C# know where the designated methods to invoke are,
>   internally?

your answer is here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S12
or in the very recommended book CLR via C#

the important thing to remember is : in .Net interfaces have nothing to do with inheritance

Comment: That link helps a lot. I appreciate it.

Comment: here's another: http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-Edition-Developer-Reference/dp/0735667454

Answer (score 7):

The reason you cannot override 'Foo' is that 'Root' has not marked it as virtual. If you mark it as virtual, it works like any other virtual method, and can be overriden as required from Child. You can think of C# as sealing interface method implementations by default. Well, anything is in fact sealed by default in C# (except finalizers of course..).

Contrast this with a language like Java, where all instance and nonprivate functions are by default virtual.

This doesn't answer how interfaces work internally, but that is related to the CLR, not to C#. Basically the CLR generates code specific to every call site of interface functions which looks up the address of the interface function it should be calling based on the object (much like normal virtual dispatch). Of course a static call can be performed when the function is not virtual, as in your case (if we have a reference to `Child` or `Root`).

Comment: And you can force-override any interface method by re-implementing it.

Comment: You can, but to access that method you still need to explicitly cast to the interface type first then, before calling the method.

Comment: This line `Well, anything is in fact sealed by default in C#` is bit confusing. Can give some explanation towards it.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. Basically I am comparing it to Java in which functions are virtual by default.

Comment: Make sense now; I have very little idea about Java; so that line confused me a bit :)

Comment: I appreciate your answer too. Thank you.